# convert Lambert 2 to WSG84

Tags: java, gis

i got latitude and longitude in lambert 2, to have a result in my map i need latitude and longitude in WSG84.

I have been searching for hours and can not find an algo or a formula to do the conversion.

Please can anyone help me.

Thaks

Comment: Not sure if there's in implementation for this. Worst case you've to do the converting by your own. Then http://math.stackexchange.com/ might be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi! Have you managed to convert your lambert2 coordinates reliably? I'm looking for a solution too... I have lambert2e coordinates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Android related question. Anyway you can use [JH Labs Java Map Projection Library](http://www.jhlabs.com/java/maps/proj/) for that or write your own maths - Wikipedia provides all required formulas.

Comment: and i did not found formula doing the job

Comment: There is no such projection as Lambert2. There are three projections named after Lambert, so you have to find out what is meant by lambert2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_projection

Comment: i just change the taken parameter to WSG84 , because i did not found the formula
It work so, so i will not convert it take more time, but it's easier now

Thanks every body

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look to the opensource GeoTools (geotools.org) java library ?
I remember we used it to convert coordinates between differents datums, years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a very simply lightweight library to cover this problem. You can found it here : https://github.com/YaGeek/lambert-java